# Postgres Array Append & Array Length for 'Array Push'

Tags: arrays, postgresql

**What is the best way to add an element to an array when the size of the array is not provided?**

With `array_append` this is what I can think of:

```
UPDATE table SET array = array_append((SELECT array FROM table WHERE ...), 'element') WHERE ...;
```

With `array_length` this is what I can think of:

```
UPDATE table SET array[array_length((SELECT array FROM table WHERE ...), 1)+1] = element;
```

Comment: So you want to append `'element'` to `table.array`?

Comment: yeah.. append 'element' to an `array` in `table.array column`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The simplest thing would be:

```
update table
set array = array_append(array, 'element')
where ...
```

or perhaps use the [`||` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html):

```
update table
set array = array || 'element'
where ...
```

Both of those are equivalent to the more common `set n = n + 11` for numbers. Depending on the types involved, you might need to disambiguate which `||` operator you mean by including a typecast:

```
update table
set array = array || 'element'::text
where ...
```

so that PostgreSQL knows you want the `array || element` version of `||` rather than the `array || array` version. Thanks to [ak5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1273174/ak5) for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: try as I might, I cannot get the second example with || to work, even though the top example works fine

Comment: DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

Comment: @ak5 Are you sure the left operand is an array?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure :/

`update users set roles = roles || 'lol' where id = 1;` no bueno

`update users set roles = array_append(roles, 'lol') where id = 1;` no problemo

Comment: @ak5 Can you reproduce it on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: @ak5 Seems to be confused by what type `'element'` is, `roles || 'cool_pipes'::varchar` works but without the cast PostgreSQL doesn't know if you're trying to `array || array` or `array || element`. I wonder if something has changed in the past eight years, I'll clarify the answer and SQL. Thanks for bugging me about this.

Comment: @ak5 BTW it works fine with integers (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad41eb/1). An string literal is sort of PostgreSQL's "could be anything" type (maybe a string, maybe an array, maybe jsonb, ...) so context often matters in strange ways.

Comment: @ak5 you have to cast the `element` to the matching type of the array eg
`array::text[] || element:text`. Empty array as example `ARRAY[]::text[] ||'element'::text`