# Append to array timestamps column a timestamp in postgresSQL

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql

In my Postgres DB I want to append a timestamp to my start_timestamps and end_timestamps column with the type timestamp without time zone[].

I am trying it the following way:

```
const stmt =
          `UPDATE position p
           SET translate_x = $1, translate_y = $2, 
           array_append(start_timestamps, $3), 
           array_append(end_timestamps, $3),
           FROM dining_table dt
           WHERE p.dining_table_id = dt.id
             AND dt.id = $3
             AND p.layout_id = $4`;
        const params = [translateX, translateY, addedTableId, layoutId, startTimestamp, endTimestamp];
```

which gives me the error:

> error: syntax error at or near "("

Any hint what I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: try replace "array_append(start_timestamps, $3)," by "start_timestamps=start_timestamps||$3" and the same for "end_timestamps"

Comment: Yes this works. Directly linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007800/postgres-array-append-array-length-for-array-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here you have to assign these results to something:

```
       array_append(start_timestamps, $3), 
       array_append(end_timestamps, $3),
```

Maybe you meant

```
       start_timestamps = array_append(start_timestamps, $3), 
       end_timestamps = array_append(end_timestamps, $3),
```